# Um objeto se comunicar com outro e vice-versa sem fazer as duas associações

Tags: java

Quero saber como eu posso criar um objeto que armazena um dado e esse dado tenha uma associação com outro objeto, exemplo, tendo dois objetos:

```
Seminario seminario1 = new Seminario("Matemática");
Aluno aluno = new Aluno("Gustavo");
```

e setando um atributo à classe aluno:

```
  aluno.setMateria(seminario1);
```

e que ao chamar a classe Seminario ele me retorne o atributo nome da classe Aluno, **SEM** precisar dar Set no seminário, exemplo:

```
seminario1.setAluno(aluno)
```

Oque pode ser feito?
(*Peço desculpas se tiver algum erro, sou novo em Java e no StackOverflow*)

Comment: Bem-vindo. Por favor forneça um [mcve]. Herança não se aplica aí.

Comment: @Piovezan acredito que melhorei um pouco, pode me dizer oque acha e se tem uma solução?

Comment: Para um objeto chamar outro ele precisa ter uma referência a esse outro objeto. Então em algum momento é preciso passar uma referência de `aluno` para `seminario`, por exemplo chamando `seminario.setAluno(aluno)` ou então então inicializando o seminário com um aluno na chamada para o construtor: `seminario = new Seminario("Matemática", aluno)`. Aí um método desse objeto `seminario` tem condições de chamar `aluno.getNome()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi bem a sua dúvida.

Sem usar o *setAluno* você terá que utilizar o relacionamento de [Associação de Classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(object-oriented_programming)) que consiste em uma forte relação de dependência, porque será necessário instanciar uma classe na outra (Aluno teria que instanciar Seminario) e que na prática é representada da seguinta forma:

```
public class Aluno
{
    private String nome
    private IList<Seminario> materias;

    public Aluno(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.materias = new List<Seminario>();
    }

    public void setMaterias()
    {
        this.materias.Add( new Seminario("Matemática") );
        this.materias.Add( new Seminario("Português") );
        this.materias.Add( new Seminario("Química") );
    }

    public IList<Seminario> obterMaterias()
    {
        return this.materias;
    }
}

public class Seminario
{
    private String nome;

    public Seminario(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Os problemas:

1. Forte relação de dependência entre as classes Aluno e Seminario.
2. A classe Aluno é responsável por criar o seminário e por salvá-los
   nesse contexto e isso viola o [Principio da Responsabilidade
   Única](https://kaiqueprazeres.medium.com/princ%C3%ADpio-da-responsabilidade-%C3%BAnica-srp-solid-b7ec76e207e) do SOLID.
3. Essa modelagem é ruim porque nesse contexto todos os alunos terão as mesmas matérias. (Isso pode ser resolvido passando os nomes das matérias por parâmetro, mas ainda não é uma solução escalável)
4. A relação não parece adequada, pois nesse contexto o Aluno possui a matéria, não o contrário.

Os itens 3 e 4 podem ser resolvidos fazendo alguns ajustes na modelagem aplicando o relacionamento por [composição](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition).

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
public class Aluno
{
    private String nome
    private IList<Seminario> materias;

    public Aluno(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.materias = new List<Seminario>();
    }

    public IList<Seminario> obterMaterias()
    {
        return this.materias;
    }

    public void setMaterias(IList<Seminario> materias)
    {
        this.materias = materias;
    }
}

public class Seminario
{
    private String nome;

    public Seminario(String nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String obterNome()
    {
        return this.nome;
    }
}

IList<Seminario> materias = new List<Seminario>();

this.materias.add( new Seminario("Matemática") );
this.materias.add( new Seminario("Português") );
this.materias.add( new Seminario("Química") );

Aluno aluno = new Aluno("Fulano");
aluno.setMaterias(materias);

for (Seminario materia : aluno.obterMaterias()) {
     System.out.println(materia.obterNome());
}
```

Nessa modelagem você tem as seguintes melhorias:

1. Modelagem mais coesa. A classe aluno não gerencia informações das
   matérias, ela guarda apenas uma lista de matérias.
2. A relação de dependência entre Aluno e Seminario se tornou mais flexível (Mas não deixou de existir porque o aluno depende de seminário) e não é mais responsabilidade do aluno saber saber como instanciar a classe Seminario e isso atende o que diz o [Principio da Responsabilidade Única](https://kaiqueprazeres.medium.com/princ%C3%ADpio-da-responsabilidade-%C3%BAnica-srp-solid-b7ec76e207e).
3. A relação entre Aluno e Seminario faz mais sentido do ponto de vista de modelagem e representação no mundo real.